# Как проигрывать звук с двух динамиков?

Tags: android, c++, аудио

У меня Pixel 2XL и у этого устройства 2 динамика один вверху и один внизу.

Для проигрывания звука я использую oboe библиотеку

https://github.com/google/oboe/tree/master/samples/hello-oboe

Но я заметил, что при проигровании звук идет только с верхнего динамика.

Для примера есть приложение на PlayMarket называется SoundCloud и когда я проигрываю звук с помощью него, то звук идет с двух динамиков.

Насколько я понимаю должна быть какае то возможность установить как я хочу проигрывать звук с одного динамика с двух или еще как то.

Но я не вижу ничего подобного в этой библиотеке

Как это сделать?

Comment: Может, стандартные способы помогут в решении проблемы?

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов что значит стандартные способы?

Comment: AudioManager, MediaPlayer, может быть, SoundPool